# extract city name from a string with node

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

My script receive a string from the user that contains city name or more than one, I want to extract the city name. My current code split the string to words based on white space but if the city name is two words that will not work.
I can have an array of expected city names and I want to match the city name of the string against that array, is there any possible way without having to use neural language processing  techniques ??

Example

```
var cities = ['Cairo', 'Dubai', 'San Francisco']
// possible strings
var user_string = 'traveling to Cairo'  // result ['Cairo']
var user_string = 'will leave San Francisco to Dubai late'   // result ['San Francisco', 'Dubai']
```

Answer (score 8):

Create a `RegExp` and use `match`

```
user_string.match(new RegExp( cities.join("|"), "gi" ) )
```

**Demo**

```js
var fnMatches = ( cities, str ) => str.match(new RegExp( cities.join("|"), "gi" ) );
var cities = ['Cairo', 'Dubai', 'San Francisco'];
console.log( fnMatches( cities, "traveling to Cairo" ) );
console.log( fnMatches( cities, "will leave San Francisco to Dubai late" ) );
```

Comment: this is good but it return the first city only (the first match)

Comment: @AhmedAtalla Yes, I noticed that and fixed as well. Please check the updates.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions to match the cities

```
for(i=0; i < cities.length; i++) {
  if(user_string.match(new RegExp(cities[i], 'i'))){
    console.log(cities[i]);
  }
}
```